# onmouseover, show large version of image

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I'm trying to show a large version of an image when you mouse over the smaller version of the image. I currently have 4 functions to do this, but was wondering if it could be accomplished by using one. The problem is, I'm not sure how to change the source path if I only have one function to do so. My code is below.

HTML: (I only have the first image with the showImage() on mouse over for testing purposes)

```
<section>
        <article>
            <header>Mouse Over and Mouse Out Events</header>
            <img onmouseover="showImage()" onmouseout="hideImage()" id="one" src="images/small/catbread1.jpg" title="catbread1" alt="Cat with bread on face 1" /> <img onmouseover="bigImage2()" onmouseout="hideImage()" id="two" src="images/small/catbread2.jpg" alt="Cat with bread on face 2" />
            <img onmouseover="bigImage3()" onmouseout="hideImage()" id="three" src="images/small/catbread3.jpg" alt="Cat with bread on face 3" /> <img onmouseover="bigImage4()" onmouseout="hideImage()" id="four" src="images/small/catbread4.jpg" alt="Cat with bread on face 4" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <header>Cat Photos</header>
            <img id="full" src="" />
        </article>
```

Javascript:

```
function hideImage() {
    document.getElementById("full").src = "";
}

function bigImage1() {
    document.getElementById("full").src = "images/large/catbread1.jpg";
}

function bigImage2() {
    document.getElementById("full").src = "images/large/catbread2.jpg";
}

function bigImage3() {
    document.getElementById("full").src = "images/large/catbread3.jpg";
}

function bigImage4() {
    document.getElementById("full").src = "images/large/catbread4.jpg";
}

function showImage() {
    document.getElementById("full").src = "images/large/" + this.title + ".jpg";
}
```

Comment: create a simple fiddle of what tried so far..

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CSS to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've arranged your images into a parallel hierarchy of `large/` and `small/` - that's great, it'll make this easy, and you're almost doing it already in `showImage`. I'm going to build this example using some [stock photos](https://www.pexels.com/search/cat/) so it visibly works.

Basically what you want to do is:

- Grab the image that's been moused over
- Replace the `small/` part of its path with `large/`
- Assign it to the `full` element

To get the image that's been moused over, pass it to `showImage` during the `onmouseover` event. The element firing the event is available as `this`.

```
<img onmouseover="showImage(this)" onmouseout="hideImage()" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/9413/animal-cute-kitten-cat-small.jpg" />
```

`showImage` accepts the parameter, and you can use `replace()` to do the path conversion, then assign it to `full` the way you already are.

```
function showImage(img) {
  var src = img.src;
  var largeSrc = src.replace('small', 'large');
  document.getElementById('full').src = largeSrc;
}
```

Pop this snippet open for a working demo:

```js
function hideImage() {
  document.getElementById("full").src = "";
}

function showImage(img) {
  var src = img.src;
  var largeSrc = src.replace('small', 'large');
  document.getElementById('full').src = largeSrc;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>Mouse Over and Mouse Out Events</header>
  <img onmouseover="showImage(this)" onmouseout="hideImage()" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/9413/animal-cute-kitten-cat-small.jpg" />
  <img onmouseover="showImage(this)" onmouseout="hideImage()" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/13937/pexels-photo-13937-small.jpeg" />
  <img onmouseover="showImage(this)" onmouseout="hideImage()" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7517/animal-sitting-animals-inside-small.jpg" alt="Cat with bread on face 3" />
  <img onmouseover="showImage(this)" onmouseout="hideImage()" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/254/pet-kitten-cat-lying-small.jpg" />
</article>
<article>
  <header>Cat Photos</header>
  <img id="full" />
</article>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give a try on simple CSS ?

```css
.badboy {
  background : url( http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB16ENqIXXXXXaUXVXXq6xXFXXXp/1000-autumn-maples-font-b-fall-b-font-font-b-scenery-b-font-jigsaw-puzzle-casual.jpg);
width: 300px;
height : 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  transition : ease all .5s
}

.badboy:hover {
   background : url( http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/48/61/6c/beautiful-scenery-around.jpg);
width: 400px;
height : 250px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
<img class="badboy">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the image I'm mousing over, I'm trying to make an image appear in another part of the webpage. Look at my code.

Comment: Your code *is* changing the image (ie. from small.jpg to big.jpg).  You can do this using CSS if the images are static as described above.